# Song: when to use remix, cover and tribute to

Tags: nouns, synonyms, terminology

If there is original song and same song performed by another artist, when to use term 'remix', 'cover', 'tribute to'?

1. Is 'remix' more suitable for electronic version of song?
2. What is the difference between 'cover' and 'tribute to'?
3. Which word to use when someone performs a song (but not sing) that was originally by another author? 
   Example: [Sungha Jung](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgmJJqpMuxU&feature=player_embedded) playing Take On Me ([originally by A-HA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgmJJqpMuxU&feature=player_embedded)).

Comment: Welcome to the site! P.S. Next time, it might save you time if you looked the word up in an on-line dictionary first, such as Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cover%20version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for a is a **[cover](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cover%20version)**, an existing song performed by a new artist, that is, not the original artist.

A *remix* is a mixture of some sounds from the original with other sounds. A common example is a pop song to which a beat is added.

A *tribute* is simply a song that is created or performed in honour of someone or something else, for example a new song written in a style similar to another song.